# include/config.h: fatal error: configs/.h: No such file or directory

Tags: yocto, u-boot

I am using Poky distro version 2.0.1 to build u-boot v2015.07 (porting task). But, I've run into the following error

```
| In file included from ./include/common.h:18:0:
| include/config.h:5:22: fatal error: configs/.h: No such file or directory
| In file included from ./include/common.h:18:0:
| include/config.h:5:22: fatal error: configs/.h: No such file or directory
| compilation terminated.
| compilation terminated.
| make[1]: *** [include/autoconf.mk] Error 1
| make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| make[1]: *** [include/autoconf.mk.dep] Error 1
| make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
```

The **config.h** file is generated by **scripts/Makefile.autoconf**. I already added config header file **include/configs/iwg20m_q7.h** and declared SYS_CONFIG_NAME in **board/renesas/iwg20m_q7/Kconfig** as follows:

```
if TARGET_IWG20M

config SYS_BOARD
       default "iwg20m_q7"

config SYS_VENDOR
       default "renesas"

config SYS_CONFIG_NAME
       default "iwg20m_q7"

endif
```

However, I don't know how $(CONFIG_SYS_CONFIG_NAME) (in *scripts/Makefile.autoconf*) can get the value of SYS_CONFIG_NAME (in *board/renesas/iwg20m_q7/Kconfig*). So, this caused a failure once generating config.h file (missing correct directory and SYS_CONFIG_NAME iwg20m_q7)

```
config.h
/* Automatically generated - do not edit */
#define CONFIG_BOARDDIR board/  -----> missing directory board/renesas/iwg20m_q7
#include <config_defaults.h>
#include <config_uncmd_spl.h>
#include <configs/.h>    -----> missing SYS_CONFIG_NAME
#include <asm/config.h>
#include <config_fallbacks.h>
```

I already tried to add iwg20m_defconfig

```
CONFIG_ARM=y
CONFIG_RMOBILE=y
CONFIG_TARGET_IWG20M=y
CONFIG_SYS_ARCH="arm"
CONFIG_SYS_CPU="armv7"
CONFIG_SYS_SOC="iwg20m"
CONFIG_SYS_VENDOR="renesas"
CONFIG_SYS_BOARD="iwg20m_q7"
CONFIG_SYS_CONFIG_NAME="iwg20m_q7"
# CONFIG_CMD_BDI is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_CONSOLE is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_BOOTD is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_IMI is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_IMLS is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_XIMG is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_ENV_EXISTS is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_LOADB is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_FLASH is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_FPGA is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_ECHO is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_ITEST is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_SETEXPR is not set
# CONFIG_CMD_MISC is not set
CONFIG_SPI_FLASH=y
CONFIG_SPI_FLASH_BAR=y
CONFIG_SH_SDHI=y
CONFIG_OF_LIBFDT=y
CONFIG_OF_BOARD_SETUP=y
```

and rebuilt, I saw that **.config** file also had been updated correctly, even added "*source "board/renesas/iwg20m_q7/Kconfig"*" line to **arch/arm/Kconfig** file.

However, the problem still was not resolved. Anyone can help me on this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi everyone, I have resolved the problem by adding <br/>

    `choice <br/>
 prompt "Target select" <br/>
    -       optional <br/>
    + default ARCH_IWG20M` <br/>

in the arch/arm/Kconfig file

Comment: And also add

`+config TARGET_IWG20M <br/>
+ bool "Support iwg20m_q7" <br/>
+ select CPU_V7 <br/>
+`
  in the arch/arm/Kconfig file

Answer (score 1):

Just like you answered it yourself, the problem occurs when your board specific Kconfig doesn't exists or doesn't contain board specific config variable (CONFIG_TARGET_IWG20M in your case) but it is present in the board's defconfig file.

As a rule of thumb, one should check contents of all the files listed in u-boot porting guide hosted by [elinux](https://elinux.org/images/2/2a/Schulz-how-to-support-new-board-u-boot-linux.pdf) under the heading "U-Boot directories".